# Can anyone help me in figuring out why I can't get Jquery shake effect to work on my div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've attached a JSfiddle of what my problem is. Everything else on the click of the button works except the shake effect and I cant seem to figure out why? I've tried changing it around etc but it still wont do it?

https://jsfiddle.net/g8t5ts8x/

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
      for(var i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        for(var j = 0; j < 16; j++) {
        $('#grid').append('<div class= square></div>');
        };
      };
      $(".square").mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).css("background-color", "#7fffd4");
      });

    //clears the canvas and resets the color on hover back to #7fffd4//
      $("#clear").click(function() {
       $("#grid").effect("shake", {times:4}, 1000);
        $(".square").css("background-color", "white");
        $(".square").mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).css("background-color", "#7fffd4");
        });
      });
      //creates a random color for each square when button is clicked//
      $("#randomcolor").click(function() {
        $(".square").mouseenter(function() {
        var randomColorChange = '#'+    (Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16);
        $(this).css('background-color', randomColorChange);
     });
      });
    });
```

```css
    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      border: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    body {
      font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
      background-color: white;
    }

    h1 {
      color: white;
      padding-top: 8px;
      padding-bottom: 8px;
      text-align: center;
      background-color: #191919;
    }

    span {
      text-decoration: underline;
      color: #7fffd4;
    }

    .buttons {
      padding-top: 10px;
      text-align: center;
      width: 480px;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }

    #clear, #randomcolor {
      margin: 5px;
      padding: 8px;
      border-radius: 1px;
      background-color: #191919;
      color: white;
    }

    .container {
      margin-top: 20px;
    }

    #grid {
      width: 484px;
      height: 484px;
      margin: 10px auto;
      border: 2px solid black;
      box-shadow: 2px 2px 30px 10px grey;
    }

    .square {
        width: 30px;
        height: 30px;
        margin: 0px;
        float: left;
        background: white;
    }
```

```html
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"> </script>
        <h1>Etch A <span>Sketch</span></h1>
        <div class="buttons">
        <button id="clear">Reset Canvas</button>
        <button id="randomcolor">Random Colors</button>
        </div>
          <div class="container">
            <div id="grid"></div>
          </div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: You also need to include jQuery UI for the effects functionality. https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ot7ev73s/

Comment: `$(".square").mouseenter(function() {` in your click event... is problematic. and redundant.

Comment: There is no need to re-establish the `mouseenter` event in your clear button's click event handler as you've already set it up in document ready.

Comment: @j08691 That's good advice. You forgot to mention, though that you also have to have code that utilizes the shake effect.

Comment: my bad i had taken it out then re-added it into the JSFiddle version it is in there! why is it redundant? if i take out mousenter on .square it will remove the effect of filling each square with a color when the mouse goes over it?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/g8t5ts8x/2/

Comment: @ScottMarcus Check out the fiddle he posted. The code is there. Apparently the code in the fiddle is different from what he posted here. Not my fault.

Comment: @j08691 thanks for taking the time to look at the JSfiddle! I forgot to add what is in there for the shake effect back into the code I entered into the question!

Comment: @Scott Marcus I understand what you mean now - the reason I did this was as a sort of reset to get the color back to the mint green after someone had click the random color button. so when the canvas is cleared the color also goes back to green as opposed to being stuck on the random color. I thought it was a nice effect

Comment: @nickyheise Then just set the color into a variable and use that variable to set the color. Re-binding the event handler is not needed.

Comment: @j08691 Not blaming you at all. Just wanted to point out that there was no code for the effect in this post.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Yep! Good point thanks! Sorry for the confusion with the actual effect at hand I am new to stack overflow and just intended to post the JSFiddle and then it didnt allow me so I copied and posted my current code out forgetting that I had removed the effect at hand as it wasnt working!! Thanks everyone!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$('selector').effect()` is a jQueryUI feature. Your fiddle does not reference the jQueryUI libs.

Include references to a CDN source such as:

> https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css
>   https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js

When I add these to your fiddle I see shaky buttons on click.

I have found to my own cost to check the separation between JQuery base and JQuery UI, and make no assumptions. JQuery swallows your errors if you refer to unknown methods in many cases so if you see something you expect to occur is not happening and it's a UI effect then check your assumptions.